# jQueryUI sortable - placeholder for the whole column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder

I need to be able to sort columns when dragging a column header horizontally.
So far, it works fine.

```
$( ".tablex thead tr" ).sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    helper: 'clone',
    axis: 'x',
    appendTo: '.tablex thead',
    start: function(e, ui) {ui.helper.hide();}
});
```

The only problem is that I can only see the table header's placeholder move while I drag the TH. I would like to be able to see the whole column move as a placeholder (or synchronized multiple placeholders).

So basically, **during** the drag and drop event, instead of seing only the TH move, I would like to see the TH and the related TD's move as well.

Is there any workaround that would allow me to do that?

I tried using this:

```
$( ".tablex thead tr" ).sortable({
    containment: ".tablex",
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: '.tablex',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.helper.hide();
        ui.placeholder.html('...recreate the column from scratch in html...');
    }
});
```

But then I get a moving table column that is confined to the TH. No way to get it to show up outside the table header.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This will not be easy to do. Basically, you have to add a "empty" cell for each row at a specific index and remove them after moving out.

Comment: Thanks Twisty. That part I figured out. Theoretically. But if you say there is no easy way to achieve what I need, I'll take your word for it.